# Google Plus ID from Gmail Address

Tags: oauth, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

In my app I've been asking for users' google plus IDs. A number of people have understandably just put their gmail addresses, rather than the multi-digit number that identifies them on Google Plus (which they probably don't know exists).

I saw a question asking for how to get an email address from a google+ ID, but I'm looking to do the opposite (so hopefully the security concerns don't apply, and this is feasible). I'd rather not message all my users to ask them to find the right number, if I can just convert the wrong form to the right one.

Also, users have already signed in via Facebook, so I'm hoping not to make them sign into G+ as well just to get their ids.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your app doing that it needs a Google+ ID? Also, one easy way to get a Google+ ID for every user is to use the new Google+ Sign-In button with a people.get('me') call on the authenticated user. The Person response contains the Google+ ID.
https://developers.google.com/+/features/sign-in

Comment: Users sometimes google hangout with each other, so it's convenient to have that info on their profiles. And I was thinking of doing that, but since people already sign in with Facebook, it feels a bit like overkill by external authentication. And I still have the problem of the people who've given their email addresses. Are there no solutions to that specific problem (gmail -> g+ id)?

Comment: No, there is currently no way to use an email address to fetch a Google+ ID. If you don't want to ask users to connect their accounts, or offer them multiple sign-in options, the only other thing I can think of is to ask them to paste the link to their Google+ profile, instead of the Google+ ID, so that they won't misunderstand. You can scrape the ID out of the URL, so long as it isn't a "verified" account. But, the truly best option would be to get them to sign in, even if it is with multiple social accounts.

Comment: Oh well. Thanks! I might just stick with basic format validations and a helpful validation method, then. I feel weird about having users sign in with one service after having signed in with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is interested in doing this:

Ended up taking Joanna's advice and having people essentially sign in via google, then using javascript to make it seem like they're just fetching their id -- retrieving from their user object their id, suppressing the post-sign-in flash, and then replacing the sign-in button with a display of their id. Fairly unobtrusive for a user.